# How could a message be returned from the function?

Tags: javascript, ibm-mq

IBM MQ, use this example
https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/master/samples/amqsbra.js

The env was configured and work correctly.
I send the message through MQ and receive it in this function.
But I don`t how to return the message from this function.

```
function getCB(err, hObj, gmo,md,buf, hConn) {
   if (err) {
     if (err.mqrc == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) {
       console.log("No more messages available.");
     } else {
       console.log(formatErr(err));
       exitCode = 1;
     }
     ok = false;
     mq.GetDone(hObj);
   } else {
     if (md.Format=="MQSTR") {
       console.log("message <%s>", decoder.write(buf));
     } else {
       console.log("binary message: " + buf);
     }
     gmo.Options &= ~MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
     gmo.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question. Post your code *here* as a [mcve]. We need to see what exactly you did, not what the example says. The example probably works, your code probably doesn't.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "return the message from this function". I don't understand that part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

> https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/master/samples/amqsbra.js

And the comments in that file say:

> This is an example of a Node.js program to browse messages from an IBM
>   MQ queue using an asynchronous method. This is a non-destructive
>   operation

Mark has put 12 Node.js / IBM MQ samples in the [mq-mqi-nodejs](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/tree/master/samples) GitHub repository (you referenced above).

> But I don`t how to return the message from this function.

If you want to put a reply message to an MQ queue then why don't you review the "amqsput.js" sample in that GitHub repository?